# Tag maintenance required

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I just went through the list of tags and found some possibilities for improvement.

We have both "high-school" and "secondary-education". Perhaps they should be merged.

We have "first" with no qualifier for questions about "FIRST programs", a real thing. Perhaps a name change since as it stands it is easily interpreted.

We have a tag about doctoral education, but none about masters. I haven't looked to see if there are existing questions that might benefit, but keep it in mind.

The tag quantum should probably be quantum-computing, though it only has one question and no wiki.

We have a few tags with no wiki. I may play with that a bit in coming days. It would be nice if all tags had guidance.

We have many (many) tags with only one question. Perhaps some of the questions should be retagged, making the tag obsolete. There is a difference between a keyword in a question and a tag. Not all users understand that. (tag "first" only has one question, so retagging might be a solution there. The other existing tags are probably sufficient.)

Comment: I've added wiki to many of the tags lacking them.